# How to setting for GridDB JDBC connect to GridDB Server run with Fix_list or provider mode?

Tags: java, jdbc, griddb

I want to setup the server with [fixed list ( or provider method) method](https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_5/GridDB_AdministratorsGuide.html?_ga=2.123968643.869712248.1623213939-886848398.1617241639#cluster-network-configuration) to run GridDB Java JDBC sample.

However, I only found the guide to [run with multicast method](https://github.com/griddb/jdbc) for GridDB JDBC. I think I must setup GridDB JDBC with fixed list mode like the server.

So I want to ask if I use GridDB server with fixed list  ( or provider method), how do I setup for GridDB JDBC (both client & server side)?

If anyone have any idea, please help me !

Answer (score 0):

These days, GridDB's default connection method is FIXED_LIST. So if you install the latest version and run everything according to their docs, it will be in FIXED_LIST mode already.

You also have some documentation on JDBC found on their site: https://docs.griddb.net/jdbcdriver/overview/

Here is a blog post showing JDBC as well: https://griddb.net/en/blog/connecting-to-griddb-via-jdbc-with-sqlworkbench-j/